# How to map dictionary keys to model fields in PeeWee with dict_to_model

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, peewee

How can I use `dict_to_model()` to populate (insert data into) a table from dictionary values without changing the model attributes? I have a model, Video, with attributes:

```
class Video(model):
    id = IntegerField()
    camera = CharField()
    channel = IntegerField()
    filename = CharField()
```

I also have a dictionary of data:

```
data = {'video_id': 1234, 'camera_name': "canon", 'channel_id': 5, 'video_name' = "intro.mp4"}
```

Each key:value pair in the dict corresponds to a column and its data. From what I understand, I can use the `dict_to_model` function from `playhouse.shortcuts` to map the dict keys to table columns and act on the values inside the dict. How can I do this without changing the names of my class attributes? The only way I could get this to work was by changing Video.id to Video.video_id so it matches the dictionary and so on. Even then, a .save() statement does not push the data to a table. If I do not change my model attributes, I get:

```
AttributeError: Unrecognized attribute "video_id" for model class <Model: Video>
```

If I change my attributes to match the dictionary, it accepts the mapping but will not send the data to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dict and model fields should match, so you have to rename either dict fields or model fields.

Also take a look at "Storing Data" section in [peewee quickstart](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#storing-data)

```py
uncle_bob = Person(name='Bob', birthday=date(1960, 1, 15))
uncle_bob.save() # bob is now stored in the database
```

Probably after converting dict to model you need to call `.save()` method

Comment: This is what I needed to hear, thank you.

Comment: Or do `Video.create(**{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', ...})`